# Crash when tapping UITableView (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview, random, crash

I`m using cocos2d-x and UIKit and I have such crash.Doest anyone has any ideas? I would be very happy to listen to anything.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b0985cc objc_msgSend + 44
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33411f60 __CFBasicHashRehash + 1612
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3333bfe8 CFBasicHashRemoveValue + 2764
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3333fe40 CFRunLoopRemoveTimer + 152
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3333fd16 CFRunLoopTimerInvalidate + 346
5   UIKit                           0x353162fc -[UIDelayedAction unschedule] + 32
6   UIKit                           0x3531bca8 -[UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer clearTimer] + 32
7   UIKit                           0x3531bb62 -[UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 30
8   UIKit                           0x3521307e -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 406
9   UIKit                           0x35212dae -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 86
10  UIKit                           0x352007fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
11  UIKit                           0x35200116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
12  GraphicsServices                0x36f035a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
13  CoreFoundation                  0x333cd680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
14  CoreFoundation                  0x333ccee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
15  CoreFoundation                  0x333cbcb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3333eeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3333ed44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
18  GraphicsServices                0x36f022e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
19  UIKit                           0x352542fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

Comment: maybe you should post some code

Comment: You should post the code, which is causing this crash. That would be more helpful.

Comment: Damn what thing is this?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, We found out that mixing C++ and Objective-C leads to such random crashes. We rewrote the entire app into Objective-C. And crashes just disappeared.